# Time series-identify pattern-Autocorrelation

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, pattern-recognition

I am studying Time series.

I am trying to identify if the pattern in the plot of residuals vs order to identify the type of autocorrelaiton:

[image]

I think that it has a negative autocorrelation because almost every negative error is followed by a positive error and vice versa. However, analyzing some examples on the internet I am now confused.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: please post the actual data ... and your model

Comment: I only need to identify the pattern to check if autocorrelation is positive negative or no autocorrelation by analysing the plot of the residuals vs time. I am confused because it does not have a cyclic pattern and I think that is negative. But I saw that to be negative all negative erros should follow a positive error and sometimes it does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

That seems pretty random to me... Deducting autocorrelation from this simple kind of graph is just terrible, just calculate it and put it on a ACF (and maybe PACF also) graph. There's much to say about autocorrelation and time series models, so I won't write any longer and I'll just let you keep studying them.

Comment: very well said !

Answer (score 0):

Seems random, but I think is a bad idea analyzing autocorrelation just with a graph (is a kind of... Subjective)

You can try with formal tests (runs, ACF, or Durbin Watson)

You are describing a runs test (viewing the sign of the errors), but as I said, that is subjective IF you just numbered the signs. At runs, you reject randomness if you have a number Of runs too small or too large.  (But how much is that? You need a p-value or a rejection region)